# how to make signature of PDF LTV enabled when using own certificates (Adobe java PDFBox)

Tags: java, adobe, pdfbox, signature

I have generated my own CA using

> ```
>  openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCAtrusted.key 2048    
>  openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCAtrusted.key -sha256 -days 1024 out rootCAtrusted.crt
> ```

I provided only country, state, locality, organisation, unit, common name and email.  I then created a client certificate to it using

> ```
>  openssl req -out client1.csr -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout client1.key
>  openssl x509 -req -days 1024 -in client1.csr -CA rootCAtrusted.crt -CAkey rootCAtrusted.key -CAcreateserial -out client1signedtrusted.crt -sha256
> ```

when I sign my pdf in Adobe with the client certificate then Adobe checks the signature and shows the client certificate is issued by the CA.  But it shows the signature as not LTV capable and does not offer the option (right click on signature) to add the information to make it LTV capable. I then used AddValidationInformation.java to add the information via code but no luck, the signature remains not LTV capable.

Do you have a hint for me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have placed several files here:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgWxt4VV8teWb74Jh-pqgk5u_lo?e=fQEvch

Comment: The files with "client1" in the name have a signature which is not LTV enabled (ocsp is the version where I modified the file using AddValidationInformation.java but the result is no different.  The files with "RM" in the name strangely HAVE a signature which is LTV enabled.  It must be related to elevating it to trust anchor.  But I cannot reproduce this using a new CA/client certificate.  In addition the RM certificate actually seems broken, AddValidationInformation.java cannot detect who issued it.

Comment: From mkls response the solution to my problem does not seem easy.  Cant I shortcut by designating a certificate as trust anchor?  Else is there a code sample for what mkl suggests?  Many thanks for the prompt and competent responses in this forum, really appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention the password of the pdf in 1drv.  It is "1234" for all of them.

Comment: *"Cant I shortcut by designating a certificate as trust anchor"* - if you explicitly trust the signer certificate in the Acrobat settings, every signature with it should display as *LTV enabled*. I say "should" because AFAIK there is no open specification of what *LTV enabled* requires, merely some more or less vague characterizations.

Answer (score 3):

*LTV enabling* a signature includes collecting revocation information (CRLs or OCSP responses) for all used certificates except explicitly trusted ones or accordingly marked OCSP signer certificates.

To do that, Adobe Acrobat needs to know where (method and URL) to retrieve such revocation information. It reads these details from properties of the certificates in question.

You don't add these details to your certificates.

To enable Adobe Acrobat to LTV enable your signatures, therefore, you have to setup an OCSP responder or a CRL download service for your micro PKI and add a reference during certificate creation.

To enable your own code you at least have to be able to create OCSP responses or CRLs for the certificates in question somehow and extend your code to make use of that ability. E.g. generate a CRL for your PKI manually, make it available to your code in the file system, and make your code include it.